# Why are there multiple script tags after building NextJS?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I ran `next build` followed by `next start`. It's still rendering with many JS files at once instead of a singular entrypoint.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here? The docs make it seem as though this is all that's needed

[image]

Comment: What else did you expected? The chunks are result of code splitting.

Comment: When I use webpack I typically have an entry file and it handles that, or so I thought?

Comment: Secondarily, my `<script src="/scripts/myfile.js" />` inside `<Head>` is not being grouped into any `_next/static/` files

Comment: It won't be grouped. It will be just emitted as a simple JS file without any optimizations. If you want it to be grouped, "import" it your code itself. Ramakay's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you see are NextJS code splitting into functional and framework code , you can read more about it here

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2#improved-code-splitting-strategy

I see a comment about a `<script` file in your head, Next will leave this alone because its just a tag being printed - if you need your own *outside* JS file to be served by Next, place it in the *public* directory.

Comment: +1. Apart from the files mentioned in the that link, there are build and SSG manifests, and a JS file corresponding to `pages/_app.js` -- it will be there in each non-API route as it creates the base.

Comment: @Ramakay makes sense now but `Cannot read property 'tagName' of null` is what I get when I change `<script src="/scripts/myscript.js" />` to `<Script src="/scripts/myscript.js" />` inside `<Head>`. `scripts` is a folder within `public`

Comment: Maybe, because you have `<Script` instead of `<script` ? - If you have a example codesandbox or similar  it would help.

Comment: @DaveStein `<Script>` should be kept outside of `<Head>`. Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script -- _"With `next/script`, you no longer need to wrap scripts in `next/head`."_

Comment: okay I'm gonna mark this answer as correct to my question but I def have more questions now :)