# Why next.js build makes serveral files in the dist directory?

Tags: next.js

I'm very new to next.js.

previously, I use webpack, and make config from scratch.
`webpack build` make the only bundle.js in dist directory (only one bundled js file)

and I make a project with next.js from scratch.
but now I tried `npm run build`, It makes too many files.
with Webpack, I only need an index.html and one bundled js file,
but, now I have no idea how to use and test with this many files.
Is there any wrong with me?

```
.
├── build-manifest.json
├── cache
│   └── webpack
│       ├── client-development
│       │   ├── 0.pack
│       │   ├── 1.pack
│       │   ├── 10.pack
│       │   ├── 11.pack
│       │   ├── 12.pack
│       │   ├── 13.pack
│       │   ├── 14.pack
│       │   ├── 15.pack
│       │   ├── 16.pack
│       │   ├── 2.pack
│       │   ├── 3.pack
│       │   ├── 4.pack
│       │   ├── 5.pack
│       │   ├── 6.pack
│       │   ├── 7.pack
│       │   ├── 8.pack
│       │   ├── 9.pack
│       │   ├── index.pack
│       │   └── index.pack.old
│       ├── client-production
│       │   ├── 0.pack
│       │   └── index.pack
│       ├── server-development
│       │   ├── 0.pack
│       │   ├── 1.pack
│       │   ├── 10.pack
│       │   ├── 11.pack
│       │   ├── 2.pack
│       │   ├── 3.pack
│       │   ├── 4.pack
│       │   ├── 5.pack
│       │   ├── 6.pack
│       │   ├── 7.pack
│       │   ├── 8.pack
│       │   ├── 9.pack
│       │   ├── index.pack
│       │   └── index.pack.old
│       └── server-production
│           ├── 0.pack
│           └── index.pack
├── react-loadable-manifest.json
├── server
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── _app.js
│   │   ├── _document.js
│   │   ├── _error.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── pages-manifest.json
│   └── webpack-runtime.js
└── static
    ├── chunks
    │   ├── amp.js
    │   ├── main.js
    │   ├── node_modules_next_dist_client_dev_noop_js.js
    │   ├── pages
    │   │   ├── _app.js
    │   │   ├── _error.js
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── polyfills.js
    │   ├── react-refresh.js
    │   └── webpack.js
    ├── development
    │   ├── _buildManifest.js
    │   └── _ssgManifest.js
    └── webpack
        ├── 496129cd3e9c913aa9ff.webpack.hot-update.json
        └── webpack.496129cd3e9c913aa9ff.hot-update.js

13 directories, 58 files
```

Here is my next.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  distDir: 'dist',
  webpack: function (config, options) {
      config.experiments = {};
      return config;
  },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  env: {
    API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
    AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    PROJECT_ID: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    STORAGE_BUCKET: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    APP_ID: process.env.APP_ID,
  }
};
```

package.json script

```js
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Comment: What's the question here? You're not doing anything wrong. It's how Next.js works. This particular feature of breaking bundle into multiple chunks is known as code splitting.

Comment: @brc-dd with webpack, I only need to open index.html file to test bundle.js(webpack build output). but next build output is not simple to me, how can I test my build file?..

Comment: How were you testing the build earlier? Were you using some framework like Jest?

Comment: @brc-dd sorry for confusion, the word test is not meaning like Jest tool, I want to know how to use build file, for example `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` in index.html, so I can simply use bundle.js (output of `"build": "webpack"`)

Comment: It will be handled by Next.js itself. You just need to run [`next start`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#production). If you want to link bundle in your own file, then you can try doing [`next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export). Also can you elaborate what exactly your use-case is so that we can provide further insight? BTW [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68626904) explains what you asked in the title.

Comment: @brc-dd Thanks, I think `next export` is what I seek for, maybe I thought wrong, because I think that I need to link script between index.html and build output. but in next js, I don't need `public/index.html`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236260/discussion-between-stefancho-and-brc-dd).